# chrome print layout and more setting missing on my web page

Tags: html, google-chrome, printing, angular7, css-print

I'm working on a web application and I'm using angular 7, I didn't use any specific css for page, but when I'm going to print a web page, more setting in chrome print is not available and missing as shown in below image:

[image]

But in every other page on the internet which I see, more setting and layout are present and I want it like below image:

[image]

Why it is hiding only in my web page?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  When I removed all @page rules, the print layout option comes back.

Comment: This was driving me nuts, but I removed tailwindcss and only kept basic styles, no page or media rules and got it the extra options to appear

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your specific question but I can tell you that it seems like others are experiencing this annoyance as well. Also, I found that for some reason, by selecting a portion of text prior to launching the print element and then checking "selection only", the "more settings" option appears again. The downside is that the preview seems to be reloaded, which means that if there are specific elements which one wants to capture, they may be changed respectively reset by this process.